# Count occurences in a column instead of row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is the table I am working on:

[image: table image]

I want to count the number of times P occurs for each user( x216001,x2016002,..). How can I do it?

I would also like to know if I can create a colum in that table itself, which can count the number of P's.

Comment: When would 1 equal 'P'? 'P' is 'P', and 1 is 1. That aside, this problem is symptomatic of appallingly poor design. Stop. See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalise your table structure to store values in multiple rows with tags. However here is a method

```
select 
case when col1='P' then 1 else 0 end +
case when col2='P' then 1 else 0 end +
case when col3='P' then 1 else 0 end +
.
.
.
case when colN='P' then 1 else 0 end 
as counting
from table
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Is there any way I could use a for loop for doing those task instead or repeating each line? Because in 'colN', N is a variable that could change. Any help would be great.